# AppBarLayout with weird shadow at borders

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I need my AppBarLayout to have a transparent background.

When I change the background of the AppBarLayout to have @null or @android:color/transparent I got a weird shadow at the border of the Toolbar.

If I set the background as a color the toolbar looks normal.

This is my layout xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#4999E2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          android:importantForAccessibility="no"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_calendar_check"/>

      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

AppBarLayout with a color as background:
(android:background="#4999E2")

[image]

AppBarLayout with a null background
(android:background="@null")

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

This happens, because `AppBarLayout` has a default `stateListAnimator` which applies elevation in a collapsed state.

If you want to get rid of this effect, do this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    ...
 />
```